# Why won't my page render or export using html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

My first post here, so forgive any etiquette slips.

I am creating a page whereby the user can customize a card...that functionality is not a problem. But I need to export an image of the card, and cannot make that happen. I have tried the code from the html2canvas site, among many other versions, trying even to render the whole document, from this page and others. But I get nothing, save for a few errors I don't understand.

Here's the page: https://interrobangtype.co/resources/business-card-maker/
Upon clicking the submit button, I see this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: CanvasRenderingContext2D.createPattern: Passed-in canvas has height 0`

My code specific to this function is here:

```
<canvas class='hidden card' style='width: 3.5in; height: 2in;'></canvas>
<button onclick="Submit();" class='download-card button' id='download-card' >Submit</button>
                        
<script type="text/javascript">
var Submit = function() {
html2canvas(document.body, {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
$('canvas.card').removeClass('hidden');
}
});
}
</script>
```

Any insight? I tried it by letting the plugin append the canvas as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is not clear from your example if you are loading all the proper JavaScript Libraries. Please confirm that all the proper libraries are loading.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I am, in fact, loading all the libraries needed. jQuery, then jQuery UI, then specific plugins such as html2canvas (which seems to be loading but encountering problems). The navigation and font page functionality confirm that the other libraries are loading and functioning properly.